# Perl's regular expression modifier

Tags: regex, perl

What does the following Perl regular expression modifer do?

```
/o
```

For example,

```
$string =~ /foo\(\"([^\)]*)\"\)/o)
```

What does the `/o` mean?

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550258/does-the-o-modifier-for-perl-regular-expressions-still-provide-any-benefit) for more discussion about `/o` modifier.

Answer (score 6):

It tells Perl to only compile the expression once. See *[What is /o really for?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#What-is-%2Fo-really-for%3F)*.

Answer (score 5):

> The /o option for regular expressions (documented in perlop and perlreref) tells Perl to compile the regular expression only once. This is only useful when the pattern contains a variable. Perls 5.6 and later handle this automatically if the pattern does not change.

([source](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#What-is-/o-really-for?))

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely nothing!

It affects interpolation, and nothing is being interpolated into that pattern.

Were there something interpolated, /o would cause the interpolation to only happen once, no matter how many times the match operator is executed.

```
>perl -E"for (['o','foo'],['a','bar'],['e','neo']) {
    my ($pat, $s) = @$_; say $s =~ /$pat/ ? $& : 0 }"
o
a
e

>perl -E"for (['o','foo'],['a','bar'],['e','neo']) {
    my ($pat, $s) = @$_; say $s =~ /$pat/o ? $& : 0 }"
o
0
o
```

Comment: And even when there is interpolation, it does almost nothing! And even when it *does* do something, you probably didn't want it to! So there's not a lot of point in using /o.

Comment: @hobbs, I agree fully. It's much better to use qr//.