# How to I read in a line and delimit it with '!!" in C++?

Tags: c++, string, delimiter, getline, cin

I have tried using `getline()` but the `delimiter` being set to "`!!`" causes the program to not compile. I need it the string read into a string variable called messages. My code looks like this... Help?

```
cout << "Enter the message> ";
getline(cin, message, "!!");
```

Comment: You cannot use a multiple-character delimiter in `getline` - it takes a delimiter *character* (not a delimiter string), hence the compilation error (a string cannot be used where a char is expected). See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for more info - there's no overload that takes a delimiter string. You'll need to either choose a 1-character delimiter instead, or use a different method of handling your input stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the std function properly. You are trying to pass a string for the delimiter rather than a character. If that is the delimiter you need, getline will not help you off-hand.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Here you can find a working code for what you would like to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string message;
    cout << "Enter the message>";
    cin >> message;
    cout << message.substr(0, message.find("!!")) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You need to run this command or something similar for your scenario: `g++ main.cpp && a.out`

Output is:

```
Enter the message>sadfsadfdsafsa!!4252435
sadfsadfdsafsa
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.substr(0, inStr.find("!!"));
```

Example: http://codepad.org/gPoqJ1Ie

[Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c)

dmitri explains why the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

getline() accepts char as delimiter, "!!" is a string

```
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);
```

That is why your code doesn't compile

1. Read input char by char and **tokenize it yourself.** The [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) method
   will be helpful or you may look at [boost.tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/tokenizer/).
2. Use '!' as a parameter in getline() or getdelim() to read a string and wait for next '!', continue accumulating the string if not '!'