# How to parse second part of Text (1. / 2. line)?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file, parsing

I have a text file including following text

```
zts1e   Generelle Effekte
zts2e   Magische Effekte
zts3e   Gift Serie
zts4e   Krankheitsserie
zts5e   Aufladungs Serie
```

And what to do if I want to have the second part of the 1st line ("Generelle Effekte") and (ex.) the 2nd part of the 2nd line ("Magische Effekte") and so on?

I mean I have parsed a long time ago something else but I don't know how to manage it.

Could you help please?

Comment: Depends on exactly what the format of the file is. You have to define that first. Is it always 5 characters, a tab, then the rest is a second field? Or is it some arbitrary number of alphanumerical characters, some arbitrary white space, and then the rest of the text? Or something else?

Comment: *Please* show us what you've already tried. At least do some research by yourself. (Even just opening the file, for starters.)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c) will do this for any line format. Just use `tab` or `space` as a delimiter.

Comment: this is a txt-file, and between the string name "ztsXe" and the German text is always a tab. It goes on with zts<number>e descending.  The German text is some times one word, sometimes to, sometimes some more.

Comment: First you divide the file by lines (`\n` or `\r\n`, depending of the platform you're using) and it creates an array of lines. Then you divide each line by `\t` (if the space between the two texts is a tabulator) and you can place it to a hashmap for example, so you will get an array of elements with key consisting of the first text, and corresponding value as the second text.