# Parse only specific columns from csv file using token

Tags: c++, file, parsing, csv, ifstream

If I have a file filled with comma separated values, such as this:

```
"myComputer",5,192.168.1.0,25
"herComputer",6,192.168.1.1,26
"hisComputer",7,192.168.1.2,27
```

And I want to pull the data out as a string, I would do something like this:

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream myfile ("myCSVFile.txt");

if(myfile.is_open())
{
    while(getline(myfile,line))
    {
        std::string tempString = line;
        std::string delimiter = ",";
    }
}
```

In order to parse out each value by itself, I use something like this: [Parse (split) a string in C++ using string delimiter (standard C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c)

```
std::string s = "scott>=tiger>=mushroom";
std::string delimiter = ">=";

size_t pos = 0;
std::string token;
while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
    token = s.substr(0, pos);
    std::cout << token << std::endl;
    s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
}
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

The question is, what if I only want, the first and third value?  So if I wanted my csv file from above, to only output

```
"myComputer" 192.168.1.0
"herComputer" 192.168.1.1
"hisComputer" 192.168.1.2
```

Is there a way to achieve this using the methods above, or should I use a completely different method?  Thanks,

Comment: Use a counter in the while loop for counting column number and only output the columns you want? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Just.. don't output the second column....

Comment: Commas are not necessarily delimiters.  In particular, if you find a comma inside a quoted string, that's not a delimiter.  Your approach assumes otherwise.

Comment: Yes, it does assume otherwise.  For this problem, let's assume that commas will only be used as delimiters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to use a dedicated library for this task. With [Boost Tokenizer's Escaped List Separator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/tokenizer/escaped_list_separator.htm), it's a breeze:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream myfile("myCSVFile.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(myfile, line))
        {
            typedef boost::escaped_list_separator<char> Separator;
            typedef boost::tokenizer<Separator> Tokenizer;

            std::vector<std::string> tokens;
            Tokenizer tokenizer(line);
            for (Tokenizer::iterator iter = tokenizer.begin(); iter != tokenizer.end(); ++iter)
            {
               tokens.push_back(*iter);
            }

            if (tokens.size() == 4)
            {
                std::cout << tokens[0] << "\t" << tokens[2] << "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cerr << "illegal line\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in C++11, you can simplify the loop:

```
for (auto &token : tokenizer)
{
    tokens.push_back(token);
}
```

As you can see, the idea is to just store all values of a line in a `std::vector` and then output what's required.

Now this *may* lead to performance problems if you really deal with huge files. In that case, use a counter together with the tokenizer:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream myfile("myCSVFile.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(myfile, line))
        {
            typedef boost::escaped_list_separator<char> Separator;
            typedef boost::tokenizer<Separator> Tokenizer;

            Tokenizer tokenizer(line);
            int count = 0;
            for (Tokenizer::iterator iter = tokenizer.begin(); (iter != tokenizer.end()) && (count < 3); ++iter)
            {
                if ((count == 0) || (count == 2))
                {
                    std::cout << *iter;
                    if (count == 0)
                    {
                        std::cout << "\t";
                    }
                }
                ++count;
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can use both techniques (`std::vector<std::string>` with later output **or** loop with counter) even with your self-made string-splitting algorithm. The basic idea is the same:

With `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
    token = s.substr(0, pos);
    tokens.push_back(token);
    s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
}

if (tokens.size() == 4)
{
    std::cout << tokens[0] << "\t" << tokens[2] << "\n";
}
else
{
    std::cerr << "illegal line\n";
}
```

With a counter:

```
int count = 0;
while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos && (count < 4)) {
    token = s.substr(0, pos);

    if ((count == 0) || (count == 2))
    {
        std::cout << token;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\t";
        }
    }
    ++count;
    s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, and providing more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments above suggested, the answer was to only output the columns I wanted.  I implemented it by adding a counter with a loop that does the actual printing.  Instead of a while, I could have easily added the counter into a for loop, but I didn't.

```
std::string s = "scott>=tiger>=mushroom";
std::string delimiter = ">=";

size_t pos = 0;
std::string token;

int counter = 0;
while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) 
{
    token = s.substr(0, pos);

    if(counter == 0 || counter == 2)
    {
        std::cout << token << std::endl;
    }


    s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
}
```

Oddly enough, I was thinking about the problem incorrectly, and the very simple comments of, "Only print the ones you want" actually helped.  Thanks