# Parsing and turning a string into a number

Tags: c++

I have an input file which I'm reading in with the basic `myFile >> variable` since I know the format and the format will always be correct. The file I'm reading in is formatted as `instruction <num> <num>` and to make `>>` work, I'm reading everything in as a string. If I have 3 variables, one to take in each piece of the line, how can I then turn string <1> (for example) into int 1? I know the string's first and last characters are brackets which need to be removed, then I could cast to an int, but I'm new to C++ and would like some insight on the best method of doing this (finding and removing the <>, then casting to int)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse (split) a string in C++ using string delimiter (standard C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c)

Answer (score 1):

use stringstream

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str = "<1>";
    int value;
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    char c;

    ss >> c >> value >> c;

    std::cout << value;
}
```

Comment: got it, this works, initially I had `value` as a string and it wasn't getting rid of the last `>`, but I changed it and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First to get the middle character out you can just do `char myChar = inputString.at(1);`.  Then you can do `int myInt = (int)myChar;`

Comment: Incorrect, and also using C-style casts. The stringstream answer above is better, and can also be wrapped in a templated function.

Comment: it won't always be a one-digit number though. I'm trying to use .erase() on the string to get rid of the first and last iterator to erase the <> but its not working as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you remove the `<>` characters, your still importing the file content into a string using `>>` so you still need to cast it to an int. If you have only 1 value, you can follow what Nicholas Callahan wrote in the previous answer, but if you have multiple characters you want to read as int, you dont have a choice but to cast.

Answer (score 0):

You can also resort to `sscanf`.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "<1234>";
    int value;
    sscanf(str.c_str(), "<%d>", &value);
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```