# Split string and get values before different delimiters

Tags: c++, string, split

Given the code:

```
procedure example {
  x=3;
  y = z +c ;
  while p {
    b = a+c ;
  }
}
```

I would like to split the code by using the delimiters `{`, `;`, and `}`. 
After splitting, I would like to get the information before it together with the delimiter.

So for example, I would like to get `procedure example {`, `x=3;`, `y=z+c;`, `}`. Then I would like to push it into a `list<pair<int, string>> sList`. Could someone explain how this can be done in c++?

I tried following this example: [Parse (split) a string in C++ using string delimiter (standard C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c), but I could only get one token. I want the entire line. I am new to c++, and the list, splitting, etc. is confusing.

Edit: So I have implemented it, and this is the code:

```
size_t openCurlyBracket =  lines.find("{");
size_t closeCurlyBracket = lines.find("}");
size_t semiColon = lines.find(";");

if (semiColon != string::npos) {
    cout << lines.substr(0, semiColon + 1) + "\n";
}
```

However, it seems that it can't separate based on semicolon separately, openBracket and closeBracket. Anyone knows how to separate based on these characters individually?

2nd Edit:
I have done this (codes below). It is separating correctly, I have one for open curly bracket. I was planning on adding the value to the list in the commented area below. However, when i think about it, if i do that, then the order of information in the list will be messed up. As i have another while loop which separates based on open curly bracket. Any idea on how i can add the information in an order?

```
Example: 
 1. procedure example {
 2. x=3;
 3. y = z+c
 4. while p{
```

and so on.

```
while (semiColon != string::npos) {
        semiColon++;
        //add list here
        semiColon = lines.find(';',semiColon);
    }
```

Comment: In your example on what you would like to get, the `while` loop is missing. Is this intentional? If yes, what are your exact criteria to parse the code?

Comment: @honk Sorry, if i was unclear. It was just an example of the things i want. while is included as well. I have successfully separated them now, am trying to put it in a list now.

Comment: User @user3188346 suggested to use the `find_first_of` function in his answer. That should help you to preserve the order of lines. Did you try that?

Comment: @honk I was trying my way, which was not working. And when i tried his code, it worked. Haish. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should read about [std::string::find_first_of function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/).

```
Searches the string for the first character that matches any of the characters specified in its arguments.
```

I have a problem to understand what you really want to achieve. Let's say this is an example of the `find_first_of` function use.

```
list<string> split(string lines)
{
    list<string> result;
    size_t position = 0;

    while((position = lines.find_first_of("{};\n")) != string::npos)
    {
        if(lines[position] != '\n')
        {
            result.push_back(lines.substr(0, position+1));
        }
        lines = lines.substr(position+1);
    }

    return result;
}
```