# How to return position of last char occurance?

Tags: c++, string, split

I'm using [WDL_String](https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol/blob/master/WDL/wdlstring.h) container to manage string within a C++ Framework. I need to split a string (delimiter `\`) and get the last occurrence.

I can use the native method:

```
mFilePath.DeleteSub(mLastOccPosition, mFilePath.GetLength());
```

subbing the string, but I don't know how to catch the `mLastOccPosition`.

So if I have this string:

```
D:\\Google Drive\\My Files\\Test.zip
```

I need to return `Test.zip`. What's the best way to do this in C++?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c

Comment: @F.bernal: I'm not using `string`

Comment: use const char *Get() const and then create your std string

Comment: If I am not mistaken, according to the code you linked, doesn't `mFilePath.get_filepart()` give you what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `s` is an instance of `std::string`, then `s.find_last_of('\\')` would do it.

It returns `std::string::npos` if it can't be found.

You can then use `std::string::substr` to extract the bit you need.

Comment: As I said, I'm not working with string. But WDL_String. I can get `char*` from WDL_String.

Comment: Well, you did ask for the best way, and that's probably to write `std::string s(/*the function that gets the char* */)`, and go from there. There's no point in building the extraction code from scratch.

Comment: Is it nice somethings like this? (I don't need any reference to string): `(string(mFilePath.Get())).find_last_of('\\')`

Comment: That would do it. (Although you might want to keep the string around if you want to use it for the extraction of the file name). Note that `std::string::npos` is a *constant* and does not require a string instance.