# QT C++ read file with both int and QString each line

Tags: c++, string, qt

I am trying to read in a text file and then parse each line into 3 variables. Two of them are `QStrings`, and one of them is an `int`. Each line of the file will look like this:

```
This is my first string : This is my second string : 2
This is another first string : This is another second string : 18
```

Based on this, as I iterate through my file, I would like to set each variable (QString1, QString2, int) and then call a method.

```
QString1 = "This is my first string"; 
QString2 = "This is my second string"; 
int x = 2;

callMethod(QString1, QString2, x);

QString1 = "This is another first string"; 
QString2 = "This is another second string"; 
int x = 18;

callMethod(QString1, QString2, x);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: It seems like your lines are broken up by a colon (i.e. s : s : 1) is that correct?

Comment: No not lines, each variable value is. All 3 variables will be on 1 line, separated by " : "

Comment: [look at his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c) which addresses how to split a string on a delimiter character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the file line-by-line and then simply parse the results as they flow through. Here is an example:

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDebug>

void MainWindow::parseFile()
{
    QFile inputFile(QFileDialog::getOpenFileName());
    if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
       QTextStream in(&inputFile);
       while (!in.atEnd())
       {
           QString text = in.readLine();
          if (!text.isEmpty())
          {
              QStringList line = text.split(':');
              callMethod(line[0], line[1], QString(line[2]).toInt());
          }
       }
       inputFile.close();
    }
}

void MainWindow::callMethod(QString first, QString second, int third)
{
    qDebug() << "Variable #1: " << first;
    qDebug() << "Variable #2: " << second;
    qDebug() << "Variable #3: " << third;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: @user3781214 Anytime!

Comment: Why did you create a new QString from a QString in order to call .toInt()? `QString(line[2]).toInt()`

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd do it with proper error checking.

Since it's a text file, you'd set a `QTextStream` on it, and read it line-by-line. You immediately `split` the line on the colon separator, and check if you've got three pieces. It is not necessary to check for an empty `line`, since `split` can handle empty strings, as well as strings with no separators.

If you got three pieces, parse the last piece to an integer and check if it succeeded. If it did, you can call your method, passing it the first two pieces with whitespace (if any) trimmed, and the integer you parsed.

You most likely want whitespace trimming, so that the behavior for the string parts is the same as for the integer part: `toInt` ignores whitespace, after all.

Output:

```
read "a1" "b1" 10
read "Lol" "cats" 33
```

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/simple-parse-37902620
#include <QtCore>

void callMethod(const QString & a, const QString & b, int c) {
   qDebug() << "read" << a << b << c;
}

void parse(QIODevice * input)
{
   QTextStream in(input);
   while (!in.atEnd()) {
      auto const line = in.readLine();
      auto const parts = line.split(':');
      if (parts.size() == 3) {
         bool ok;
         auto p3 = parts.at(2).toInt(&ok);
         if (ok)
            callMethod(parts.at(0).trimmed(), parts.at(1).trimmed(), p3);
      }
   }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
   QByteArray data{" a1 :  b1  : 10   \nLol:cats: 33"};
   QBuffer buf(&data);
   if (buf.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
      parse(&buf);
}
```