# C++ function running twice but only called once

Tags: c++, shell, unix

I am learning C++ [Java background fwiw] and trying to write a UNIX shell as a project. I am running into a funny little problem with tokenizing the input for execution. The tok function is getting called twice and I'm not sure why. My current test code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

using namespace std;

void tok(string, char**);

int main(){
    const char* EXIT = "exit";

    string input;

    cout << "shell>> ";
    getline(cin, input);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    char* args[64]; //arbitrary size, 64 possible whitespace-delimited tokens in command
    tok(input, args);
    return 0;
  }

  //copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c
void tok(string inStr, char** args){
    int last = 0, next = 0, i = 0;
    while( (next = inStr.find(' ', last)) != -1){
        cout << i++ << ": " <<  inStr.substr(last, next-last) << endl;
        *args++ = strdup(inStr.substr(last, next-last).c_str());
        last = next + 1;
    }
    cout << i++ << ": " << inStr.substr(last) << endl;
    *args++ = strdup(inStr.substr(last).c_str());
    *args = '\0';
    cout << "done tokenizing..." << endl;
}
```

My output when I actually run the program is:

```
$ ./a.out 
shell>> ls -l
0: ls
1: -l
done tokenizing...
0: ls
1: -l
done tokenizing...
```

I'm not sure why it would do that. Can anyone guide me in the right direction please? Thank you

Comment: You called `fork`  and then called a function. Of course it will be called twice. You need to check the id if you only want one of the processes to call `tok`

Comment: While it is up to you, the recommendations I've seen are to not call `using namespace std;` globally.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I totally forgot that the fork was called above. If you put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: The `fork()` function duplicates the process and *both* processes continue to run from the point after calling fork.   Why is fork being called?

Comment: Also "*I am learning C/C++*" -- well, no. You are either learning C or C++, but they are entirely different (though related) languages at this point in time, and have been for the better part of 3 decades. Good luck with your learning, but are fantastic language.

Comment: Side note: lots of `strdup()`s no `free()`s. I would just use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thats correct, I had overlooked that. Ideally, I would want to free after I have executed the commands. I am still trying to figure out how to iterate over the `char**`, I keep getting segmentation faults.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I see, I will change the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `fork`, you create two processes. Each process has nearly the exact same state except for the respective `pid_t` you receive. If that value is greater than 0, then you are in the parent process (main), and otherwise you are in the child (or fork failed).

Without performing a check on the returned `pid_t`, both processes will call `tok`, resulting in the double call behavior you witnessed.

Hide the call behind a check on `pid` like so:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid > 0) // have parent process call tok
{
   char* args[64]; //arbitrary size, 64 possible whitespace-delimited tokens in command
   tok(input, args);
}
```

To see what else parent and child processes have in common (or not): check the [docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Answer (score 9):

The `fork` function returns twice, once in the original process and once in the newly-created, forked process. Both of those processes then call `tok`.

There doesn't seem to be any clear reason why you called `fork`. So the fix may be as simple as eliminating the call to `fork`.

Answer (score 1):

following code may work fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

using namespace std;

void tok(string, char**);

int main(){
const char* EXIT = "exit";

 string input;

 cout << "shell>> ";
 getline(cin, input);

// pid_t pid = fork();

 char* args[64]; 
 tok(input, args);
 return 0;
}


void tok(string inStr, char** args){
int last = 0, next = 0, i = 0;
while( (next = inStr.find(' ', last)) != -1){
    cout << i++ << ": " <<  inStr.substr(last, next-last) << endl;
    *args++ = strdup(inStr.substr(last, next-last).c_str());
    last = next + 1;
}
cout << i++ << ": " << inStr.substr(last) << endl;
*args++ = strdup(inStr.substr(last).c_str());
*args = '\0';
cout << "done tokenizing..." << endl;
}
```