# Strange behaviour in declaration inside a while condition C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am implementing a python like `split()` function in C++ to train myself. I got the idea from this SO thread: [Parse (split) a string in C++ using string delimiter (standard C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c)

In this code:

```
while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
    token = s.substr(0, pos);
    std::cout << token << std::endl;
    s.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
}
```

The value os `pos` is assigned inside the condition of the `while` loop.

I tried the same thing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string inp, std::string delimeter){
    std::vector<std::string> res;
    while (size_t pos = inp.find(delimeter) <= inp.length()){
        std::cout << inp << "   " << pos << std::endl ;
        if (inp.substr(0, delimeter.length()) == delimeter) {
            inp.erase(0, delimeter.length());
            continue;
        }
        res.push_back(inp.substr(0, pos));
        inp.erase(0, pos);
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    for (auto i : split(",,ab,c,,d", ",")){
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

My output is:

```
,,ab,c,,d   1
,ab,c,,d   1
ab,c,,d   1
b,c,,d   1
,c,,d   1
c,,d   1
,,d   1
,d   1
a b c
```

My question is why poes it say that the position of `,` in string `,,ab,c,,d   1` is `1`?

And why is the position in `ab,c,,d` is 1 as well?

I modified the code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
...
    size_t pos = 0;
    while (pos <= inp.length()){
        pos = inp.find(delimeter);
        ...
}

int main() {
    for (auto i : split(",,ab,c,,d", ",")){
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Where `...` remains unchanged and now it works like a charm, the output is:

```
,,ab,c,,d   0
,ab,c,,d   0
ab,c,,d   2
,c,,d   0
c,,d   1
,,d   0
,d   0
d   18446744073709551615
ab c d
```

Just as I expected.

So my question is: Why cant i declare a variable inside a while condition? Isnt the condition is evaluated at all cycle (thus the declaration happen again?) Even at the very first cycle i get the result `1` which is wrong. Why is that?

Comment: Your statement about the first code sample is wrong. And that makes the question confusing! `pos` has been declared before the loop.

Comment: In the first code `pos` is not declared in the for loop.  it is declared somewhere before it as it should be.

Comment: "Why cant i declare a variable inside a while condition?" you can.  just remember that the scope of the variable is reset on each iteration of the loop

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes sorry you are right, it is declared somewhere else, but it is assigned inside the condition of the for loop. Thats what i wanted to say.

Comment: So maybe edit your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while (size_t pos = inp.find(delimeter) <= inp.length()){
```

is interpreted as

```
while (size_t pos = (inp.find(delimeter) <= inp.length())){
```

while you need a completely different grouping

```
while ((size_t pos = inp.find(delimeter)) <= inp.length()){
```

The latter is illegal in C++ though.

It is not possible to declare a variable in `while` condition and at the same time make it participate in a more complicated conditional expression (like a comparison with another value). When you declare a variable in C++ condition all you can have is its initial value converted to bool.

The modified code, where `pos` is declared before the loop, properly implements your intent.

Comment: So i was checking a condition and got a boolen 1. That explains it, and its so clear..  I was only sitting here for like and hour to find it out.. Thanks a lot, i ll mark this as correct as soon as i can (10 minutes)