# How to efficiently read only strings from a big txt file

Tags: c++, string, file, fstream

I have a very big .txt file (9 MB). In it the words are stored like this :

```
да 2337093
е 1504540
не 1480296
се 1212312
```

Every line in the .txt file consists of a string followed by a single space and a number.
 I want to get only the words and store them in a string array. I see that a regex will be an overkill here, but fail to think of a another way as i'm not familiar with streams in c++.

Comment: Nine megabytes is not very big. Just open it, use `std::getline()` to read each line, and `find()` to locate the delimiting space. If you are guaranteed that the contents of the file will always be well-formed, then you might as well just use `operator>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to below sample

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> strings;
    ifstream file("path_to_file");
    string line;
    while (getline(file, line))
        strings.push_back(line.substr(0, line.find(" ")));

    // Do whatever you want with 'strings' vector
}
```

Comment: [Don't use bits/stdc++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Answer (score -1):

You should read file line by line, and for each line use string's `substr()` method to parse a line based on space location, and you can use `find()` method to find the location of delimiter. take the word part which is before space and ignore rest.

You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c) for an example.

Comment: There's no split function.

Comment: I missed that question was for C++, Still, there is a lot of available API's for string methods or you can make your own using `substr()` method. See the updated answer.