# Parsing fields from stdin in C++

Tags: c++, string, parsing

If I have the `stdin` input as follows:

```
2014-01-23,  AA, 20
2014-05-30,  BB,2    //notice that I might have optional space
2015-03-24, CC,   5
//...
//... and so on
```

How do I write a program in C++ that efficiently parse the **month** and **year**, and also subsequent field? I am really stuck by this parsing issue.

What I want to do with the subsequent field is stored `AA, 20` as a map. So `map[AA]=20` so on.

I can do this myself. But I can't figure out how to read and parse it.
Please help.

---

Attempt:

```
int year, month;
int  num;
string key;
map<string, int> mapping;
string s;
getline(cin,s, '-'); 
year=stoi(s); 
getline(cin,s, '-');
month=stoi(s); 
getline(cin,s, ',');
//reading the AA, BB, CC field;
getline(cin,s, ',');
for (int i=0; i<s.size(); i++);
   if (s[i]==' ') s.erase(i,1);
key=s;
//now, reading the number field following AA,BB, CC
getline(cin,s,'\n');
for (int i=0; i<s.size(); i++);
   if (s[i]==' ') s.erase(i,1);
num=stoi(s);
mapping[key]=num;
```

Comment: You need to take this one step at a time. First, write a program that reads each line of text, one line at a time. Step two: parse each line of text into the individual fields. Step three: parse the first field into its component, year, month, and day. Problem solved. See how easy it was?

Comment: yes, that is easy. But my code is a little bit long.

Comment: There's an old Vulcan proverb: the longer the code, the likelier is that it has a bug.

Comment: Just need help to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) (or [`Boost.Regex`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) if you're on an "ancient" compiler)

Match the line with this

```
(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2}),\s*(.+),\s*(.+)
```

then get year, month, day, first field, second field from the match groups \1, \2, \3, \4, \5 respectively

Comment: if I have a very large amount of data (many lines to read), do you think this method would still be efficient?

Comment: It depends. The only way to know is benchmarking it. A compiled regex can be reused and therefore have quite good performance and can be easily changed unlike a fixed parser

Comment: This might be a dumb question. How do I use`\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}),\s*(.+),\s*(.+)` with regex?

Comment: [learn](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) about [tag:regex] first then use [`regex_search` or `regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) like in the example

Answer (score 0):

An answer to a similar problem was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c) using [std::basic_string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find). You can use `-`, , and `,` as delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s;
    char c;
    int x;
    cin >> s >> c >> x;
    s = s.substr(0,s.length() - 2);
    cout << s << " " << c << " " << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. This answer was a few years ago and my knowledge was very limited