# Store .txt file into a char* 2d Vector C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I know there are lots of questions with similar titles here, but no one seems to work for me. 
I have this kind of txt file:

```
tree pine
color blue
food pizza
```

and I want to store the items in a char* 2d vector, such as

```
vector<vector<char*>> data;
..
..
data[0][0] = tree
data[0][1] = pine
data[1][1] = blue
ecc
```

This is the code:

```
// parse configuration file
bool Configuration::fileParser(char* filename)
{
    vector<vector<char*>> data;
    fstream fin("data/setup.txt");
    string line;
    while (fin && getline(fin, line))
    {
        vector<char*> confLine;
        char* word = NULL;
        stringstream ss(line);
        while (ss && ss >> word)
        {
            confLine.push_back(word);
        }
        data.push_back(confLine);
    }
    storeData(data);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run the code an exception is thrown.

```
Exception thrown: write access violation.
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: "How can I solve this problem?" Start by using `std::string`.

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: On which line / in which function is the exception being thrown? How is `storeData` implemented? We don't know the background of your project so you must give as complete information as you can.

Comment: You could parse the file line by line then parse the line into a vector table.  I can give you example code but before I do that.  Is the number of words in each line constant?

Comment: Thanks @AlexG, Yeah, it could be just 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I do not have a compiler on hand to test the following code with files, but it should work.

Here is a reference I used: [Parse (split) a string in C++ using string delimiter (standard C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c)

**Discription:** Basically the following code parses the passed in file line by line then assigns the first word and second word into the vector.  Notice that I used `string`(s) in the example because I didn't want to think about memory management.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void Configuration::fileParser(string fileName)
{
    vector<vector<string>> data;

    ifstream configFile(fileName);
    string line, token;
    string delimiter = " ";
    size_t pos;
    if (configFile.is_open())
    {
        int n = 0;
        while (getline(configFile, line))
        {
            if (!line || line == "")
                break; //added as a safety measure
            pos = 0;
            if ((pos = line.find(delimiter)) != string::npos)
            {
                token = line.substr(0, pos);
                data[n][0] = token; //add first word to vector
                line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
            }
            if ((pos = line.find(delimiter)) != string::npos)
            {
                token = line.substr(0, pos);
                data[n][1] = token; //add second word to vector
                line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
            }
            n++;
        }
    }
    storeData(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated any memory into which the data can be written. You'd need something like `char* word = new char[50];`. But just use a `std::string` it is safer and easier.