# Split string by delimeter

Tags: c++, arrays, string, parsing

I have recently been trying to use TinyXML2 to read/write XML files, but I encountered a problem. I am trying to read a integer array that I exported from another program and it loads but TinyXML won't read integer arrays and I can't convert constant characters pointers to integers.

I want to separate comma separated values and store them in a array.

My code is as follows.

```
    int GetMapData (const char* XMLFile) {
        int mapdata[1];
        XMLDocument File;
        File.LoadFile(XMLFile);
        const char* data = File.FirstChildElement("map")->FirstChildElement("layer")->FirstChildElement("data")->GetText();
}
```

Comment: Use atoi() to convert strings to integers.

Comment: You need to parse the string contents. How you do that depends on what format it has.

Comment: @Michael Never use atoi() for anything.

Comment: What is wrong all of a sudden with atoi() ? Except of course, for the old garbage-in garbage-out paradigm...

Comment: @MichaëlRoy You can't tell the difference between zero and failure, for one. `atoi` is garbage-in zero-or-undefined-out.

Comment: @Michael There is nothing "suddenly" wrong with it - it has always been useless, and there have always been far better alternatives.

Comment: Your opinion, not mine.

Comment: I've found what I've been looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update with commas**

```
#include <sstream>

// ... 

char const *ss = "1, 2, 3, 4";  // this come from the FirstChildElement method in your case.
istringstream buffer(ss);
int value1, value2, value3, value4;
char c;
buffer >> value1 >> c >> value2 >> c >> value3 >> c >> value4;
cout << value1 << "-" << value2 << "-" << value3 << "-" << value4  << endl;

output: 
1-2-3-4
```

are you looking for something like this?

of course you have to polish it, but It should give the idea.
**Kasper**

Comment: Yes similar but the values are separated by commas and i want it stored to a array. Thank you i will try too modify the code.