# String Line Commands in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have to make a code that read a line strings from user and divides this string when there is a space, store and then do some operations with this input.

**For example the input can be like That :**

```
"set 11643133 name Alex Jon"
```

all this it have to be input in a one line, and I have to divide it for set a name "Alex Jon" to the student's ID "11643136"

I really have to hand the project in nearest time, I just want to ask if there is a **simple way** or some **standard commands** maybe can it helps me at that **?**

*I use `getstr()` and `string.substr()`

Comment: Use `std::getline` to read lines of text. Then, use the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/the-most-elegant-way-to-iterate-the-words-of-a-string to split a line into tokens. Process the tokens using whatever logic makes sense.

Comment: This question already got an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c

Comment: I think this is the 5th homework assignment I see tonight XD.... Nevertheless; be aware when splitting on a space, most systems use `"` to combine "separated" arguments. (you might need it with "Alex Jon")

Comment: `strtok` is a simple C function for tokenising strings. Code would look something like this (can't post answer bc closed). https://gist.github.com/Robadob/e7a6d96afebc57fbafd7f0ec904a1a84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem boils down to splitting the string by spaces. You can use the `istringstream` for splitting. Then apply whatever logic you have on these tokens.

```
string s;
getline(std::cin,s);
istringstream iss(s);
vector<string> tokens;
string tmp;

//read tokens
while(iss>>tmp) {
    tokens.push_back(tmp)
}
```

Now `tokens` consisits of all your words given by the user as an input.