# How to split a std::string into a range (v3) of std::string_views?

Tags: c++, string, range-v3, string-view

I need to split a `std::string` at all spaces. The resulting range should however transform it's element to `std::string_view`s. I'm struggling with the "element type" of the range. I guess, the type is something like a `c_str`. How can I transform the "split"-part into `string_view`s?

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include "range/v3/all.hpp"

int main()
{
    std::string s = "this should be split into string_views";

    auto view = s 
            | ranges::view::split(' ') 
            | ranges::view::transform(std::string_view);
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

(One of) the problem here is that `ranges::view::split` returns a range **of ranges**, and you cannot construct a `std::string_view` directly from a range.

You want something like this:

```
auto view = s
    | ranges::views::split(' ')
    | ranges::views::transform([](auto &&rng) {
            return std::string_view(&*rng.begin(), ranges::distance(rng));
});
```

There might be a better/easier way to do this but:

- `&*rng.begin()` will give you the address of the first character of the chunk **in the original string**.
- `ranges::distance(rng)` will give you the number of characters in this chunk. Note that this is slower than `ranges::size` but required here because we cannot retrieve the size of `rng` in constant time.

Comment: Final `view` is probably `string_view` of single elements

Comment: @P0W No! `split` does not "return" a range of character, it returns a range **of range**, so each `rng` is itself a range of character corresponding to a word inside `s` (a pair of iterators to `s`), which is why I can construct a `std::string_view` from it.

Comment: Thanks for the [P1989R2](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2021/p1989r2.pdf) and [P2210R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2210r2.html), the `return std::string_view(&*rng.begin(), ranges::distance(rng));` can be simplify into `return std::string_view(r);`.

Answer (score 2):

Now that we are in the golden era of C++23, we have a bunch of new ways supported by the standard library:

```
auto view = s | std::views::split(' ')
              | std::views::transform([](auto rng) { 
                  return std::string_view(rng.data(), rng.size());  // C++20 (subrange::data(), size())
                  // return std::string_view(rng.begin(), rng.end());  // C++20
                  // return std::string_view(rng);  // C++23
            });
```

But I don't see any point to transform a view of subranges (the output of split()) to a view of string_views.

If your final objective is to split at space and concatenate the subranges into a string, it can be easily done as follows:

```
auto str = s | std::views::split(' ') 
             | std::views::join
             | std::ranges::to<std::string>();  // requires C++23
```