# How to split a std::string_views into a tuple-like objects using C++20 std::views::split?

Tags: c++, split, c++20, stdarray, stdtuple

According to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402558/how-to-split-a-stdstring-into-a-range-v3-of-stdstring-views), we can using C++20's [`std::views::split`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) to split `std::string_view` into range of `std::string_view`s:

```
std::string_view s = "this should be split into string_views";
auto views = s | std::views::split(' ')
               | std::views::transform([](auto&& rng) {
                   return std::string_view(&*rng.begin(), std::ranges::distance(rng));
                 });
```

If I want to store those `std::string_view`s into some tuple like objects such as `Boost.Fusion.Sequence`, `std::tuple`, or `std::array`:

```
// magic function
auto tuple_like = to_tuple_like(views);
```

How can I do that? Is there any solution that no need to create intermediary like `std::vector`? Note that the origin `s` is not `constexpr`.

Comment: Do you *have* to store the strings in a `tuple`?

Comment: A tuple is a heterogeneous container why would you use it for homogeneous elements? Second, a tuple size is set at compile time, while your number of tokens is known at runtime.

Comment: @NicolBolas In some case, I need to parse those  `std::string_view`s (maybe "1", "0.34", "hello") and store the values of different types to some user-defined `struct` using `boost::fusion` reflection tricks (i.e., `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`).

Comment: @康桓瑋: My understanding is that `boost::fusion` can take `std::array`s or similar aggregates as inputs to its processes.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, Ok then seems I need to change my questions. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example implementation of the "magic function" to turn your view into a tuple of string views

```
#include <iostream>

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t tup_size>
struct TupleType {

};

/*
must be manually defined for each size you want to support
*/
template <>
struct TupleType<6> {
    using type = std::tuple<
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view>;
};

template <>
struct TupleType<7> {
    using type = std::tuple<
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view>;
};

template <std::size_t idx, class Tup, class It>
constexpr void TupleAssignImpl(Tup& tup, It& it) {
    std::get<idx>(tup) = *it;
    ++it;
}

template <class Tup, class It>
constexpr void AssignEachImpl(Tup& tup, It& it) {
}

template <std::size_t idx, std::size_t ... Is, class Tup, class It>
constexpr void AssignEachImpl(Tup& tup, It& it) {
    TupleAssignImpl<idx>(tup, it);
    AssignEachImpl<Is...>(tup, it);
}

template <class Tup, class It, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr void AssignEach(Tup& tup, It& it, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    AssignEachImpl<Is...>(tup, it);
}

template <std::size_t size, class Range>
constexpr auto ToTuple(Range const& rng) {
    auto tup = typename TupleType<size>::type{};
    auto it = std::ranges::begin(rng);
    AssignEach(tup, it, std::make_index_sequence<size>{});
    return tup;
}

int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view s = "this should be split into string_views";
    constexpr auto views = s | std::views::split(' ')
                   | std::views::transform([](auto&& rng) {
                   return std::string_view(&*rng.begin(), std::ranges::distance(rng));
                 });
    constexpr auto sz = std::distance(
        std::ranges::begin(views),
        std::ranges::end(views));
    auto tup = ToTuple<sz>(views);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(tup),  std::tuple<
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view,
    std::string_view>>);

    std::cout << std::get<0>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<1>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<2>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<3>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<4>(tup) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<5>(tup) << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
this

should

be

split

into

string_views
```

A few comments:

In general there may be (probably are) better ways to achieve this. This is just my approach.

I feel it is a bit clunky to have to manually define specializations of `TupleType` for each size of tuple you want to support. Although since the type of the tuple must strictly be known at compile time I don't know another approach.

With `AssignEach` I would have much rather written a simple for loop. e.g.

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  std::get<i>(tup) = *it;
  ++it;
}
```

But of course the argument to `std::get` must strictly be known at compile time so I used `AssignEach` as a workaround.

The size of the tuple must be supplied as a template parameter to `ToTuple` since, again, in order to work we must guarantee that the tuple size is known at compile time.

As a final note: as others have pointed out, maybe the call to use `std::tuple` as opposed to a homogeneous range is questionable here. But you asked how it could be done, and this is an approach.

If you are okay with using `std::array` which is tuple-like, the approach can be much simpler. No need for the specializations of `TupleType` and the `AssignEach` workaround.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>



template <std::size_t size, class Range>
constexpr auto ToTuple(Range const& rng) {
    auto array = std::array<std::string_view, size>{};
    std::copy(std::ranges::begin(rng), std::ranges::end(rng),
              array.begin());
    return array;
}


int main() {
    constexpr std::string_view s = "this should be split into string_views";
    constexpr auto views = s | std::views::split(' ')
                   | std::views::transform([](auto&& rng) {
                   return std::string_view(&*rng.begin(), std::ranges::distance(rng));
                 });
    constexpr auto sz = std::distance(
        std::ranges::begin(views),
        std::ranges::end(views));
        
    auto tup = ToTuple<sz>(views);

    for (const auto str : tup) {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
}
```

note: output is the same as the tuple example

Comment: Rather than `std::tuple`, why not `std::array`, which is similarly [tuple-like](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/tuple_element)

Comment: honestly not sure. i did tuple because the question asked for tuple (: edit: oh i see it says "tuple like" not just tuple. maybe i will update with an array approach (which i think would be simpler)

Comment: yes the std::array approach is much simpler. ive edited my answer to include that. thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: "*must be manually defined for each size you want to support*" That looks like a C++98 solution. There have to be better metaprogramming techniques than that these days.

Comment: @NicolBolas feel free to suggest one. as i said i am not aware of one. note: i have added an approach that uses std::array that doesnt not require the specializations

Comment: I like your solution so I upvote, but, in reality, the origin std::string_view is usually not `constexpr`.

Comment: understood. in that case i am not sure it is possible to obtain a tuple like structure. at least i would not know the way.