# Why can't I construct a string_view from range iterators?

Tags: c++, c++20, string-view, std-ranges

C++20 adds a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) for `basic_string_view` which takes two iterators. However, when I try to construct a `string_view` with the iterators from a common range I get an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

using namespace std::views;

int main()
{
    auto words = "the quick brown fox" | split(' ') | transform([]<class RNG>(RNG&& rng) {
        auto v = std::views::common(std::forward<RNG>(rng));
        return std::string_view(v.begin(), v.end());
    });
    for (auto&& word : words) {
        std::cout << word << std::endl;
    }
}

<source>:11:6:   required from here
<source>:10:21: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_string_view<char>::basic_string_view(std::common_iterator<std::ranges::split_view<std::ranges::ref_view<const char [20]>, std::ranges::single_view<char> >::_InnerIter<true>, std::default_sentinel_t>, std::common_iterator<std::ranges::split_view<std::ranges::ref_view<const char [20]>, std::ranges::single_view<char> >::_InnerIter<true>, std::default_sentinel_t>)'
10 |         return std::string_view(v.begin(), v.end());
    |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

https://godbolt.org/z/E4779G

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a std::string into a range (v3) of std::string\_views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48402558/how-to-split-a-stdstring-into-a-range-v3-of-stdstring-views)

Comment: @康桓瑋 actually the question you linked is only tangentially relevant here

Comment: @bartop By tangentially, you mean it's exactly the same question but just about range-v3 instead of C++20?

Comment: @Barry no, I mean that though code is similar, the questions are rather different

Comment: You can't really split a string literal: the trailing null after "fox" will be included in the last word. Make sure you cast to a `string_view` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the requirements imposed on the [iterator constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) for `std::string_view`:

> This overload only participates in overload resolution if
>
> - It satisfies contiguous_iterator,
> - End satisfies sized_sentinel_for for It,
> - std::iter_value_t and CharT are the same type, and
> - End is not convertible to std::size_t.

Your range iterators do not satisfy at least the first requirement

Comment: Why would these iterators not be contiguous?

Comment: Because `std::views` are generally lazy, which makes iterators naturally non-contiguous. I think the strictest you can get from lazy view is forward iterator (not fully sure here)

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now.

Comment: @Chris_F See [P2210](https://wg21.link/p2210), which will make the this case just work.