# Join a container of `std::string_view`

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, string-view

How can you concisely combine a container of `std::string_view`s?

For instance, `boost::algorithm::join` is great, but it only works for `std::string`.
An ideal implementation would be

```cpp
static std::string_view unwords(const std::vector<std::string_view>& svVec) {
  std::string_view joined;
  boost::algorithm::join(svVec," "); 
  return joined;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A `string_view` is contiguous. Outside of *very* specific circumstances, two unrelated `string_view`s are not. The only way to create a contiguous range of characters from non-contiguous ranges... is to allocate a contiguous range. Like in a `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short C++20 answer version:

```cpp
    using namespace std::literals;
    const auto bits = { "https:"sv, "//"sv, "cppreference"sv, "."sv, "com"sv };
    for (char const c : bits | std::views::join) std::cout << c;
    std::cout << '\n';
```

since **C++23** if you want to add special string or character between parts you can just use simple [join_with](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/join_with_view) and your code is just below (from official [cppreference example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/join_with_view))

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
 
int main() {
    using namespace std::literals;
 
    std::vector v{"This"sv, "is"sv, "a"sv, "test."sv};
    auto joined = v | std::views::join_with(' ');
 
    for (auto c : joined) std::cout << c;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Note1:** if you do not like use not stable release of language, you can simple use [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library for `join_with` views

**Note2:** As [Nicol Bolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas) you cannot join literally to exact one `string_view` without any copy (you can copy to string and ... :D), if you want to know more detailed about that you can see [Why can't I construct a string_view from range iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66691886/1539100) SO question and answer.

Comment: What does "ITNOA" mean?