# Read white spaces in in a file C++

Tags: c++, fstream

How I can read line of a file with a whitespace, in the case that `faddress` was a string with space I will not able to read all the line.

What I can do ? I try using noskipws but it doesn't work

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/noskipws/

Code:

```
ifstream rFile;
rFile.open("list_of_people.txt");

 while(rFile  >> fname >> flastName >> ocupation>> faddress >> age){
            insert(fname,flastName,ocupation,faddress,age);
         }
```

File :

```
John Smith Engineer Av Roses 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to have the entire line in a string, then use string functions to parse it / tokenize it as you see fit. About doing that, see, for example:

[Parse (split) a string in C++ using string delimiter (standard C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14265581/1593077)

Comment: Hmm but how I can use getline with ifstream ? and I can use getline with non-strings values ?