# More elegant way to get the current year in C++

Tags: c++, time, stream, std

I'm quite new to C++. I need to get the current year and store it in an int.

I've come to this solution:

```
std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
std::istringstream iss(ctime(&result));

iss.ignore(20);
int year;
iss >> year;
```

I find this solution a bit ugly, even if it works, as it doesn't seem very robust and it takes many steps to do not very much.

Would there be a better way to do it?

Comment: "_it doesn't seem very robust_" - correct - it isn't. Read about `locale`s

Comment: @TedLyngmo In my case, I don't need to worry about time zones, if that's what you are talking about.

Comment: It's part of it, so read about `locale`s to get an idea. I might be in your timezone but have a totally different view on how to present points in time.

Comment: Is the current year UTC sufficient or do you need the current year in your local time zone?

Answer (score 11):

C++20, you can use `std::chrono` for such purpose.

[P0355R7 Extending  to Calendars and Time Zones](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0355r7.html)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <chrono>
int main()
{
    const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::format("{:%Y}", now); // => 2021
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm forced to stick to C++11 (I don't really know why).

Comment: Unbelievable! What a really old C++ you are forced!

Comment: Could a code snippet be added to this answer?

Comment: @I.Am.A.Guy I just now add an example code. Currently, msvc is the only compiler that supports P0355R7(Calendar and timezone support for chrono) and P0645R10(std::format).

Comment: Upvoted. This gets the current year in UTC.  That may be sufficient.  The OP isn't clear on that point.

Comment: You can also use `std::chrono::utc_clock`.

Answer (score 6):

The conversion of `time_t` to string with a string parsing afterwards appears to me unnecessary complicated and error-prone. As already complained in [@Ted's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58151350/more-elegant-way-to-get-the-current-year-in-c#comment102686692_58151350), this may introduce localization of text output which may make the parsing non-robust.

Together with [`std::time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time), there are available

- [`std::localtime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime)

  > Converts given time since epoch as std::time_t value into calendar time, expressed in local time.
- [`std::gmtime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/gmtime)

  > Converts given time since epoch as std::time_t value into calendar time, expressed in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Both return a pointer to a [`struct tm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm) which contains among others a public member

> `int tm_year` years since 1900

A small sample:

```cpp
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
  std::tm *const pTInfo = std::localtime(&t);
  std::cout << "Current year: " << 1900 + pTInfo->tm_year << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Current year: 2019
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44e6e6ffae566f04)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
time_t current_time;

current_time = time(NULL);
int a;
a = 1970 + current_time / 31537970; 
cout << a << " is the current year.";

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, the following `get_this_year()` function should work for you in a C++20 way.

It will return you an `int` for the current year.

```cpp
// year.cpp

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int get_current_year() {
  using namespace std::chrono;
  return static_cast<int>(
      year_month_day{time_point_cast<days>(system_clock::now())}.year());
}

int main() {
  int year = get_current_year();
  std::cout << year << std::endl; // 2022
}
```

This should compile with e.g. `g++ -std=c++20 year.cpp`.

---

But I also would like to expand it in a verbose way, explaining what happened for each step.

```cpp
// year.cpp

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int get_current_year() {
  using namespace std::chrono;
  auto now = system_clock::now();           // 1. get time_point for now
  auto today = time_point_cast<days>(now);  // 2. cast to time_point for today
  auto ymd = year_month_day(today);         // 3. convert to year_month_day 
  auto year = ymd.year();                   // 4. get year from year_month_day
  return static_cast<int>(year);            // 5. an explicit cast is required 
}

int main() {
  int year = get_current_year();
  std::cout << year << std::endl; // 2022
}
```

Now, even more verbosely, explicitly spelling out all the types -

```cpp
// year.cpp

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int get_current_year() {
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock,
                          std::chrono::system_clock::duration>
      now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::days> today =
      std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::days>(now);
  std::chrono::year_month_day ymd = std::chrono::year_month_day(today);
  std::chrono::year year = ymd.year();
  return static_cast<int>(year);
}

int main() {
  int year = get_current_year();
  std::cout << year << std::endl; // 2022
}
```

---

There are essentially 2 types of format to represent a point in time:

1. serial-based - e.g. this time point is `x` seconds since an epoch (e.g. 1 Jan 1970)
2. field-based - e.g. this time point is `year/month/day`

From the system clock we get a serial-based time point. We need to convert it to a field-based time point. Then from this field-based time point we extract the year.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way:

```
string timestamp_str = __TIMESTAMP__;
auto timestamp_tokens = split(timestamp_str, ' ');
std::cout << timestamp_tokens[timestamp_tokens.size() - 1] << std::endl;
```

The *split()* function splits the string by the delimiter 'space'. You may write a custom method to get the last token instead(the last token is year). You can get the implementation of *split()* from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c). Here's a sample implementation:

```
vector<string> split(string string_with_delim, char delim)
{
    auto i = 0;
    vector<string> result;

    auto pos = string_with_delim.find(delim);

    while(pos != string::npos)
    {
        string res = string_with_delim.substr(i, pos-i);
        result.push_back(res);
        i = ++pos;
        pos = string_with_delim.find(delim, pos);
    }

    result.push_back(string_with_delim.substr(i, string_with_delim.size()));
    return result;
}
```