# How to write tabular data in .CSV file in C++?

Tags: c++, csv, tabular

I am trying to write in a tabular form in .csv file. many string variables (freq  voltage  current  S11    S22    S21    S12) contains big data.
for exp,

[image]

... and so on ...

first I converted all variables data row into column by replacing "," to "\n", for writing in vertical form.
for exp,

[image]
convert to 
[image]

```
string voltage , freq, curt;
freq= tmp.query("*FMA?\n");
voltage = tmp.query("*VOL?\n");
curt=   tmp.query("*CURR?\n");
replace(begin(freq), end(freq), ',', '\n');
replace(begin(voltage ), end(voltage), ',', '\n');
replace(begin(curt), end(curt), ',', '\n');
filewrite << freq<< voltage <<curt;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: *.cvs or *.csv?

Comment: .csv (comma separated file)

Comment: You have to split each line at `','` and write the values in a loop with `filewrite << freq<< ' '<<voltage <<' '<<curt<<'\n';`

Comment: can you please explain briefly how to split line and how to get final data in tabular form?

Comment: [Split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c).

Comment: i already split data by using replace(begin(freq), end(freq), ',', '\n'); , which convert horizontal data into vertical form (column into rows). but when i use filewrite << freq<<voltage <<curt<<'\n'; .  This will write data in only one column , not in different column for different variables. you can see the Results picture that i uploaded.

Comment: You are not splitting. You need to split the each string and store each element in a container like a vector. Then you can iterate over the elements

Comment: I understand now, Thank you for your guidance. it is done by splitting as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Its done.
Split by "," and use token to write in tabular form.

```
ofstream filewrite;
filewrite.open("............");
string voltage , freq;
freq= "A1, A2, A3";
voltage = "B1, B2, B3";

string delimiter = ",";
    size_t pos = 0;
    string token, token2;
    while ((pos = freq.find(delimiter)) != string::npos && (pos =voltage .find(delimiter)) != string::npos)
    {
        token = freq.substr(0, pos);
        token2 = voltage .substr(0, pos);
        filewrite << token << "," << token2 << endl;
        freq.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        str2.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }

    filewrite << freq<<"," << voltage ;
filewrite.close();
```

}