# splite string using strtok function for given string not working on strings

Tags: c++, string, split, strtok

I want to split given string with delimiter "," but its give error

```
"a value of type \"char *\" cannot be assigned to an entity of type \"std::string *\"
```

hear is my code

```
      #include<iostream>
      #include<string>
      int main()
      {
      std::string str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
      std::string* ptr;          
      ptr=strtok(str,",");
      while(ptr!=NULL)
      {
         std::cout<<ptr<<std::endl;
         ptr=strtok(NULL,",");
      }
    }
```

Comment: For the C++ way to split a string, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c

Comment: Of course you can do:   const std::string test{ "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" };
 std::vector<std::string> data{};
 for (char* token = std::strtok(const_cast<char *>(test.data()), ","); token != nullptr; token = std::strtok(nullptr, ",")) {
  data.push_back(token);
 }