# How to assign words from csv assign to variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I have a code that reads a file with a following:
word1,word2,word,3....,word8
word1,word2,word,3....,word8
word1,word2,word,3....,word8

```
ifstream infile;
    //string path;s
    infile.open("file.csv");
    string line;
    CourseNode *current = head;
    int i=1;
    if(infile.is_open()){  
    while(getline(infile, line)) { 
        if(i == 1)
            cout << "1st line==> "+line << endl;  // ignore first line
        else {    // read data
        string firstname, lastname, id, a,b,c,d,t ;
        stringstream sst(line); 
        getline(getline (sst, firstname, ','),lastname, ',');
        //getline(getline(getline (sst, firstname, ','),lastname, ','),id, ','); 
        cout << "result==> "<< firstname<<" "<<lastname << endl;
    }  
    i++;
    }
```

I assume i have to work with this line and insert there my string variables but i am not sure how!
getline(getline (sst, firstname, ','),lastname, ',');

Any help will be appreciateed! Thank you!

Comment: There are so many ways to split a string based on a delimiter - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c

Answer (score 0):

To read a `.csv` file you may read the entire line and split after to load easly your data:

```cpp
std::ifstream infile;
infile.open("file.csv");
std::string line;
int i = 1;

if(infile.is_open()){  
    while(getline(infile, line)) { 
        if(i == 1) {
            // ignore line
            continue;
        } else {    // read data
            std::vector<std::string> value; // this is where you stock the data
            value = split(line); // add your implementation of split
            // here: do something with the data in value
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

You have in `value` every data from a line of your `.cvs` file. Now, you can assigne every case to a specific variable or put them in a list of object.

Comment: Thank you! but can you write code fully if you can, i did not study vector and not sure about some things in your code

Comment: You don't know how to use vector or you can't use it? And do you wan't a split function example?