# How to split each line from a file efficiently in c++

Tags: python, c++, split, getline, stringstream

I want to process each line of a file, and then split it by a delimiter and get for example first and third token.

In python,

```
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        tokens = line.split("|")
        print(tokens[0], tokens[2])
```

So, cpp, I can read the lines of a file with `getline`. Like this:

```
ifstream fin(f);
string myStr;

while( getline(fin, myStr)){

}
```

Now, how to split the myStr with `|` and get the tokens? I tried to call `getline(myStr, token, '|')` inside the while loop again, but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: `getline(myStr, token, '|')` doesn't work because `getline` requires a `std::istream` as first parameter. You would need to use an intermediate `std::stringstream`. Not sure if it's the most efficient though.

Comment: Also check out the discussion here on splitting on a delimiter in C++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: ONLY NEED THE FIRST THREE TO FOUR TOKENS**

Try this in your while loop:

```
size_t pos = 0;
vector<std::string> tokens;
while ((pos = myStr.find("|")) != std::string::npos) {
    tokens.push_back(myStr.substr(0, pos));
    myStr.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    if(tokens.size() == 4){
        break;
    }
}
tokens.push_back(myStr)
```

And initialise `tokens` outside and before the while loop:

```
vector<int> tokens;
```

MODIFIED VERSION OF AN ANSWER FROM THIS QUESTION: [Parse (split) a string in C++ using string delimiter (standard C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c)

Comment: Thanks. It works. However, I need another suggestion. `myStr` is too long, and contains like 70-80 tokens. However, the tokens I need are just the first 3-4. So, is there a way not to read the whole string, and split, and only read the first 3-4 and break? I tried, but it doesn't work. Should I post a separate question?

Comment: I've edited the code by adding `if(tokens.size() == 4){break;}`, which breaks the loop that looks for tokens when you have exactly four tokens i.e. the length of the vector `tokens` is four. Just adjust that number if you need more or less tokens.