# Split a string of tab separated integers and store them in a vector

Tags: c++, string, fstream, ifstream

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("graph.txt");
string line;
while (getline(infile, line))
{
       //TODO
}
infile.close();
```

I am taking input line by line from the file and storing each line in the string "line".

Each line contains integers separated by tabs. I want to get these integers separated and store each integer inside a vector. But I don't know how to proceed. Is there something like a `split` function for strings in C++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse (split) a string in C++ using string delimiter (standard C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c) [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37454181/4165552) is my favorite solution.

Comment: If it's the presence of tabs that is holding you back, be aware that tabs are considered as [whitespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) for the purposes of [stream extraction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The duplicate has some solutions, I would, however, prefer to use a `stringstream`, something like:

```
#include <sstream>

//...

vector<int> v;

if (infile.is_open()) // make sure the file opening was successful
{
    while (getline(infile, line))
    {
        int temp;
        stringstream ss(line); // convert string into a stream
        while (ss >> temp)     // convert each word on the stream into an int
        {
            v.push_back(temp); // store it in the vector
        }
    }
}
```

As [Ted Lyngmo stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987040/split-a-string-of-tabs-separated-integers-and-store-the-integers-in-a-vector/66987220?noredirect=1#comment118408692_66987220)  this will store all the `int` values from the file in the vector `v`, assuming that the file in fact only has `int` values, for example, alphabetic characters or integers outside the range of what an `int` can take will not be parsed and will trigger a stream error state for that line only, continuing to parse in the next line.

Comment: I'm thinking about how to formulate the last sentence a littler better since it will not store _all_ integers if it encounters a line like `1 2 FOO 3 4`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, that is true, I'm assuming the file olny has integers.

Comment: @anastaciu yes, it only has integers, thank you