# Copying text from a Memo by line/index

Tags: c++, c++builder, rad-studio

I was wondering if there is a way to copy text from a specific line of memo. For example, I want to store the content from the 3rd line of my memo to a string, then do some operation on that string and copy it to another memo/edit.

I've tried a few variations of this, but none work:

```
str_temp = Memo1->Lines[2].Text;
Memo2->Lines->Append(str_temp);
```

when I ask from `Lines[0]` it simply copies everything from the memo into the string:

```
str_temp = Memo1->Lines[0].Text;
Memo2->Lines->Append(str_temp);
```

Comment: shove Lines[0] onto a string stream and then read line or use the find function (new like delimiter is usually '\n') https://stackoverflow.com/a/46931770/14237276

Comment: I'm using a very old version and if I remember correctly `Lines` is a `TStrings*`, so I use `Lines->Strings[index]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Lines` property is a *pointer* to a `TStrings` object. So `Memo1->Lines[2].Text` is the same as doing `(*(Memo1->Lines+2)).Text` per *pointer arithmetic*, which is syntaxically valid but logically wrong as it will end up accessing invalid memory. Whereas `Memo1->Lines[0].Text` is the same as doing `(*(Memo1->Lines)).Text` (aka `Memo1->Lines->Text`), which is both legal and valid but is not the result you want.

`TStrings` has a `Strings[]` property, that is what you need to use instead, eg:

```cpp
String str_temp = Memo1->Lines->Strings[2];
```

Alternatively, `TStrings` has an `operator[]` that uses `Strings[]` internally, eg:

```cpp
String str_temp = (*(Memo1->Lines))[2];
```