# Read Numbers from txt file with C++

Tags: c++

So in my text "123456789#987654321" is written. And in C++ i got 2 int called numbers1 and numbers2. I want numbers1 to be 123456789 and numbers2 will be 987654321.
Could you please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;

    ifstream in_file;
    in_file.open("your_text.txt");
    if (!in_file.is_open()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    string text;
    getline(in_file, text);

    size_t first_end = text.find_first_of("#", 0);
    string parsed1(text.substr(0, first_end));
    size_t second_begin = first_end + 1;
    string parsed2(text.substr(second_begin, text.size() - second_begin));

    int num1 = stoi(parsed1);
    int num2 = stoi(parsed2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to split the text by '#'

look here
[How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

and
[Parse (split) a string in C++ using string delimiter (standard C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c)

for examples.