# How to find certain substring in string and then go back to certain character?

Tags: c++, string

I save messages in string and I need to make filter function that finds user specified word in those messages. I've split each message by `'\n'` so the example of one chat would be:

`user1:Hey, man\nuser2:Hey\nuser1:What's up?\nuser2:Nothing, wbu?\n` etc.

Now user could ask to search for word `up` and I've implemented a search like this:

```
for (auto it = msg.cbegin(); (it = std::find(it, msg.cend(), str)) != msg.cend(); it++)
```

and I could put that string into stringstream and use `getline` to `\n`, but how do I go backwards to previous `\n` so I can get full message? Also, what about first message, cause it doesn't start with `\n`?

Comment: Hmm... I would say that it is time to get away from the keyboard and wonder what you want to do with those *messages*. Conceptually, you have a sequence of messages. You should think a moment about what attributes each message should have and actions you would like to realize on it. From that point you could design classes and convert your looong string to a list or vector of instances of those classes. That could be cleaner and easier to maintain than a very clever spaghetti code around a simple string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you split the strings, I image you have a vector of strings where you want to find `up` for example. You would do something like this

```cpp
for (const auto& my_string: vector_of_strings){
    if (my_string.find("up") != string::npos) { 
        // message containing up is my_string
    }
}
```

In case you haven't split the strings in a vector you can use this func [inspired by this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14266139/10875953):

```
vector<string> split(const string& s, const string& delimiter){
    vector<string> ret;
  size_t last = 0;
  size_t next = 0;
  while ((next = s.find(delimiter, last)) != string::npos) {
      ret.emplace_back(s.substr (last, next - last));
      last = next + 1;
    }
  ret.emplace_back(s.substr(last));
  return ret;
}
```

If this function doesn't work you can always take a look at [How do I iterate over the words of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string)