# std::vector string whitespace manipulation

Tags: c++, stdvector, stringstream, istream

Given a string of which the content could be `"this is a test string jump‎ ‏‏‎ ‎‎fox string"`.

There are 2 things to note from this string - there is one space between every word, but also at a specific point there is two spaces between `"jump"` and `"fox"`.

I wish to `push_back()` each individual word into a different index of `std::vector`, but I do not want to remove whitespace that is length 2 in size. E.g. the space between `"jump"` and `"fox"`. Whitespace which is 1 in size can be removed.

For example, the following code:

```
std::stringstream m(string);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> begin(m);
std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
std::vector<std::string> myvector(begin, end);
```

Places all individual words into a `vector` at different indexes, but also removes the whitespace of lengths 1 and 2.

Summarised: I would like to place each word in the string into a separate index of `std::vector`. There must be no whitespace after any word in any index. There must be no whitespace of length 1 in any index on its own. Only whitespace of length 2 i.e. between `"jump"` and `"fox"` should be placed into its own `std::vector` index.

I am aware that this is a very niche question, but I am sure there must be a way around this.

Comment: split the string at two whitespaces then split the resulting strings at single whitespace.

Comment: Simply iterate through the string, character by character, implementing the appropriate logic to do this. Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as short, brief sentences in plain English. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Comment: [std::adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find), and have the stop condition be two consecutive spaces.

Comment: If it's really only about single/double space, just copy-paste this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46931770/4165552 to split a string, and then substitute every empty element with double space.

Comment: @Mutlithrd Given your exaple string, what do you want the `vector` to look like, exactly? Your description sounds like you want this: `["this", "is", "a", "test", "string", "jump‎", " ", ‎‎"fox", "string"]`, is that right?