# I have a problem with User Authentication

Tags: c++, authentication

My problem here is that I did my first C++ Project which is a User Authentication project and everything works perfectly fine but just one tiny problem. The thing is that Once the user signs up with lets say  two words and it gets stored and I try logging in with that full name it gives me a user login failed meanwhile the txt file shows that the username entered is actually correct. But with a single word for user name signup it actually works. Any help?

Here is my code;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string User_Option;


    cout << "Do you want to Login Or Signup" << endl << endl;
    getline(cin, User_Option);
    transform(User_Option.begin(), User_Option.end(), User_Option.begin(), ::toupper);



    string Username_In_System;
    string Password_In_System;
    string Username;
    string Password;



    if (User_Option == "SIGNUP" || User_Option == "SIGN UP"){

    ofstream RecordFile;
    RecordFile.open("record.txt");

    cout << endl << endl << "USER AUTHENTICATION" << endl;

    cout << endl << "|*****************|" << endl;

    cout << endl << "SIGN UP FORM" << endl;



    cout << endl << "Enter Username: " << endl;

    getline(cin, Username_In_System);

    cout << endl << "Enter Password: " << endl;
    cin >> Password_In_System;

    cout << endl << endl << "Registration Success" << endl;

    RecordFile << Username_In_System << "   " << Password_In_System << endl;
    RecordFile.close();

    }


    else if (User_Option == "LOGIN" || User_Option == "LOG IN" || User_Option == "SIGNIN" || User_Option == "SIGN IN"){

    ifstream InputFile;
    InputFile.open("record.txt");


    cout << endl << endl << "USER AUTHENTICATION" << endl;

    cout << endl << "|*****************|" << endl;

    cout << endl << "SIGN IN FORM" << endl;



    cout << endl << "Enter Username: " << endl;
    getline(cin, Username);

    cout << endl << "Enter Password: " << endl;
    cin >> Password;

    if (InputFile >> Username_In_System && InputFile >> Password_In_System && Username_In_System == Username && Password_In_System == Password) {

        cout << endl << "Login Success" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << endl << "Login Error" << endl;
    }

    InputFile.close();

    }



     else {
        cout << endl <<"Input Error" << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I Literally expect it to work but the white space in the words at login is the problem and i'm sure.

Comment: unrelated: [why is `using namespace std` bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std)

Comment: Well, that definitely can help https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/4165552

Comment: And as to why your password comparison doesn't work, just look at the [docs of operator<<](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) for `std::string`. Simple `std::cout << Password_In_System << " vs " << Password << std::endl;` would also tell you what your problem is.

Comment: Do not tag `onelogin`.  Please read what the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onelogin) represents.

Comment: You are not reading the data the same way you wrote it. `RecordFile << Username_In_System << "   " << Password_In_System << endl;` vs `InputFile >> Username_In_System && InputFile >> Password_In_System;`

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon could you please explain further?

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is that you didn't try to follow the guidelines and didn't provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then, you didn't try to test and debug your code.

We can clean your approach a little bit by encapsulating signin and signup routines:

```
void signup(std::ostream& record, std::istream& userInput) {
    std::string username;
    std::string password;
    std::getline(userInput, username);
    std::getline(userInput, password);
    record << username << "   " << password << std::endl;
}

// almost copy-paste of your approach
void signin(std::istream& record, std::istream& userInput) {
    std::string username;
    std::string password;
    std::getline(userInput, username);
    std::getline(userInput, password);
    std::string usernameInSystem;
    std::string passwordInSystem;
    if (record >> usernameInSystem && record >> passwordInSystem && usernameInSystem == username &&
        passwordInSystem == password) {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Login Success" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Login Error" << std::endl;
        std::cout << usernameInSystem << " vs " << username << std::endl;
        std::cout << passwordInSystem << " vs " << password << std::endl;
    }
}

TEST(xxx, yyy) {
    std::stringstream signupInput("John Smith\n123\n");
    std::stringstream signinInput("John Smith\n123\n");
    std::stringstream record;
    signup(record, signupInput);
    signin(record, signinInput);
}
```

and see that the output of the program is

```
Login Error
John vs John Smith
Smith vs 123
```

So, it's clear that your `signin` function has a bug, it assumes that login and/or password does not contain any whitespaces. Let's try to fix the bug:

```
// credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46931770/4165552
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string s, std::string delimiter) {
    size_t pos_start = 0, pos_end, delim_len = delimiter.length();
    std::string token;
    std::vector<std::string> res;

    while ((pos_end = s.find(delimiter, pos_start)) != std::string::npos) {
        token = s.substr (pos_start, pos_end - pos_start);
        pos_start = pos_end + delim_len;
        res.push_back (token);
    }

    res.push_back (s.substr (pos_start));
    return res;
}

void correctedSignin(std::istream& record, std::istream& userInput) {
    std::string username;
    std::string password;
    std::getline(userInput, username);
    std::getline(userInput, password);
    std::string usernameInSystem;
    std::string passwordInSystem;
    std::string line;
    std::getline(record, line);
    // your delimiter is "3 spaces" - probably not the greatest choice
    auto userAndPass = split(line, "   ");

    if (userAndPass.size() > 1 && userAndPass[0] == username && userAndPass[1] == password) {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Login Success" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Login Error" << std::endl;
        for(const auto& elem : userAndPass) {
            std::cout << elem << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Now using `correctedSignin` you will get "Login Success". Note that probably better choice would be to store login and password in a csv format, with `;` delimiter. Also note that this is a toy example, in real application you would never store username and password information in a plain text.

Answer (score -1):

This could be an input buffer issue with the '/n' character if I am not mistaken. cin >> and getline() together is problematic because getline() uses that end character. Trying changing to `getline(cin >> ws, Username);` from `getline(cin, Username);` and in other places where applicable.

Comment: I just did and it's still not working

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't really answer the question. Also `std::getline(std::cin >> x, line);` is not a very clean code.