# Different C++ output on ARM

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++. I have a MacBook Pro M1PRO Chip, and an Asus with a i5 8th gen with Fedora 39.

I know a bit of Java, so on my Hello World project, i tried to recreate split and trim functions, but in C+, however I'm finding something quite puzzling.

i'm using the following commands to compile, on both machines:
`g++ -std=c++20 -o hello main.cpp`

the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;


string vector_to_string(const vector<string>& v, const string& separator = "") {
    string result = "[";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        result += v[i];
        if (i < v.size() - 1) {
            result += separator;
        }
    }
    result += "]";
    return result;
}

string trim(const string& input) {
    if (input.empty()) {
        return "";
    }

    constexpr char SPACE = ' ';
    const size_t first_index = input.find_first_not_of(&SPACE);
    if (first_index == string::npos) {
        return "";
    }
    const size_t last_index = input.find_last_not_of(&SPACE);

    return input.substr(first_index, last_index - first_index + 1);
}

vector<string> split(const string& input, const char delimiter) {
    vector<string> tokens;

    size_t last_start = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (input[i] == delimiter) {
            string token = trim(input.substr(last_start, i - last_start));
            if (!token.empty()) {
                tokens.push_back(token);
            }
            last_start = i + 1;
        }
    }
    string lastToken = trim(input.substr(last_start));
    if (!lastToken.empty()) {
        tokens.push_back(lastToken);
    }

    return tokens;
}

int main() {
    const string input = "Hello world";
    const vector<string> tokens = split(input, ' ');
    cout << vector_to_string(tokens, ", ") << endl;
    return 0;
    
}
```

So I'm expecting a [Hello, world] output, which it does happen perfectly on my Linux machine.
But on Mac, every time i execute my output program, i get either the correct [Hello, world], either an incorrect [Hell, world].

It might be a hell of a world, but i would very much like to understand why this happens.
My thought is that there's something wrong with the compiler on my Mac, or ARM works weird, but i doubt it.

Also, please feel free to correct my code and judge me, it helps me learn.

Thanks!

Tried switching CPU to an intel, and worked fine.
Tried googling, can't find anything specific.
Tried asking ChatGPT but it didn't know how to answer.

Comment: Why are you using `&SPACE`?

Comment: `find_first_not_of` and `find_last_not_of` need a NUL-delimited char array parameter. You are providing just a single `SPACE` char. Or alternatively you can provide a count. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of

Comment: Tactical note: Because of the fundamental differences in ideologies between C++ and Java, Java (and vice-versa) makes a poor language to use as a basis for understanding C++. What you learn about program logic will still hold, but how you best implement that logic is often radically different.

Comment: Tactical Note: Chat GPT is a language model and the language it models is NOT C++. Take everything it says with a grain of salt, and test its output diligently.

Comment: @Eljay i was using &SPACE because i thought that if i use the address instead of the string itself, it will not copy. Now i found out that I don't need to do this. It was just me trying to optimise the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is with

```
constexpr char SPACE = ' ';
const size_t first_index = input.find_first_not_of(&SPACE);
```

inside the `trim` function.  [`find_first_not_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) expects a c-string or a `std::string` as an input.  `&SPACE` is not a c-string as it is not null terminated.  This makes your program have undefined behavior and why you you get different results from run to run.

To fix this just use a `const std::string` like

```
const std::string SPACE = " ";
const size_t first_index = input.find_first_not_of(SPACE);
```

You will also need to fix

```
const size_t last_index = input.find_last_not_of(&SPACE);
```

Using the above suggestion that would turn it into

```
const size_t last_index = input.find_last_not_of(SPACE);
```

---

As pointed out by [heap underrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458097/heap-underrun) in the comments, there is also an overload that takes just a single char, and that can be used like

```
constexpr char SPACE = ' ';
const size_t first_index = input.find_first_not_of(SPACE);
...
const size_t last_index = input.find_last_not_of(SPACE);
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a few seconds. Have an upvote :)

Comment: Another option: leave `constexpr char SPACE = ' ';` as is, but use the overload taking a single char: `find_first_not_of(SPACE)`.

Comment: @heapunderrun Good call, forgot about that overload.  I've added that into the answer.

Comment: Passing `&SPACE` to `find_first_of` and similar functions calls the overload that expects a c-string, not the overload that expects a `std::string`.

Comment: Thank you for your responses guys, this worked!!
Now I have a question here, i don't have to use the &SPACE here: input.find_first_not_of(SPACE) because the function itself will accept it as address of, correct? Which means the string will not recreate inside the function.

Comment: Also, i just found out there's this function strtok, I didn't know about it so that's why i tried to implement my own split. But hey, at least i got to learn stuff.

Comment: @Kurisuchan `strtok` is the C way to do it. If you want to see some C++ ways see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265581/parse-split-a-string-in-c-using-string-delimiter-standard-c