# What's the meaning of the perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

```
if ($key =~ /^\s*(\S.*?)\s*$/o)
```

I am especially confused about the meaning of (\S.*?).Any one can explain it for me?Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help you understand

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Regarding this specifically: `(\S.*?)`

- `(` begins your capture group (group 1)
- `\S` is non whitespace character
- `.` is any character; `*?` is "zero or more times" (non-greedy)
- `)` ends your capture group

In plain english, your entire regex says

- From the beginning of the string
- match zero or more whitespace
- start a capture group

  - look for a non-whitespace
  - followed by any character zero or more times
- end the capture group
- match zero or more whitespace
- then the end of the string

Kind of a weird regex, imho.

Comment: Check the image source :)

Comment: +1 For letting us know this site http://www.debuggex.com/. Helping a great deal in learning regex. thanks.

Comment: Hey , you said "*?" is "zero or more times",but as I know , "*" is "zero or more times",so ,what's the difference between "*?" and "*"?

Comment: @Vico_Wu `*?` is *zero or more times, as few as possible*. (`?` is *one or none*). Did the formatting of your comment get messed up?

Comment: Yes ,as I know , "?" means zero or one time ,* means zero or more times, so,why *? become zero or more times?

Comment: @Vico_Wu `*?` is just another quantifier. The quantifiers like `*` and `+` can be modified in the way *how* they match. `*?`/`+?` is the *non-greedy* version (there is also `*+`/`++` a *possesive* version). All of this is documented in the [`perlre` manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers).

Comment: Thank you very much.Ihave already refered to the perldoc about the greedy and non-greedy regex,no , I have a very clear understarding.Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The code:

```
$key =~ /^\s*(\S.*?)\s*$/o
```

will produce a string in `$1` where **all leading and trailing whitespace characters** (as defined by `\s`) **are removed**.

The *intention* of the code seems to be checking that the string does not consists only of whitespaces, and obtain a trimmed string at the same time. However, it is **only true with the assumption** that the string doesn't contain multiple lines, where the regex will fail to match. For example, `"  somestring\nsomestring   \nmore string"`.

As a summary, the cases that the test rejects are:

- Strings consisting only of whitespaces (as defined by `\s`)
- Empty string.
- Strings that matches the regex (not anchored) `/\S.*\n.*\S/s` <sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Is `.` in Perl equivalent to `[\n]`? Does it exclude anything else when `s` modifier is not in effect?</sup>

---

As for the `o` modifier at the end, it seems that it is [an obsolete modifier in the later versions of Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550258/does-the-o-modifier-for-perl-regular-expressions-still-provide-any-benefit). The modifier prevents old version of Perl from recompiling the pattern unnecessarily, but the current usage is limited to several use cases. Check the [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) documentation (search for `/o`) for more information.

Comment: You say it removes leading and trailing whitespace. More precisely, it stores the trimmed string in the special variable `$1`. Incidentally, you can shorten it a bit: `\S` might as well be `.`, since if the character in that position had been a `\s` it would have matched as part of the initial `\s*`. And `..*?` is equivalent to `.+?`. So you can change `(\S.*?)` to `(.+?)`. Alternatively, you could do something like `/(\S.*\S)/` (if you know that there are at least 2 non-whitespace characters).

Comment: @DavidKnipe: no, if you remove the \S you will make the regex match even if there are only whitespace characters.

Comment: That's true I suppose. Although it doesn't matter, assuming OP is expecting to get some non-whitespace in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Apart of the strict meaning of this regex, (well documented by @naomik), the whole instruction:

```
if ($key =~ /^\s*(\S.*?)\s*$/o)
```

means:

If `$key` matches the regex, the group `$1` will contains the same as `$key` without leading and trailing spaces.
The `\o` modifier (now obsolete), avoids the recompilation of the regex. You should use `qr/^\s*(\S.*?)\s*$/` instead :

```
my $re = qr/^\s*(\S.*?)\s*$/;
if ($key =~ $re)
```

Comment: The `/o` modifier is obsolete because perl will cache the compiled regex if it doesn't change dynamically (i.e. if no variables are interpolated). Therefore, neither `/o` nor `qr//` is neccessary here.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of info here:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions

I also use this to check regexs before I use them - I find it very helpful (and it also gives a good explanation of what each step is doing):

http://www.regex101.com/r/xV1vO6