# What's the meaning of this perl regex expression?

Tags: regex, perl

```
the regex expression is as below:
if ($ftxt =~ m|/([^=]+)="(.+)"|o)
   {
    .....
   }
```

this regex seems different from many other regex.What makes me confused is the "|" ,most regex use "/" instead of "|". And ,  group ([^=]+) also makes me confused.I know [^=] means "the start of the string" or "=",but what does it mean by repeat '^' one or more times? ,how to explain this?

Comment: your interpretation of `[^=]` is false. Brackets in regex start a class of individual characters to match, and `^` at the beginning negates it. Elsewhere inside brackets it behaves at a literal characters (and many other characters lose their special meaning inside brackets). Without brackets, `^=` would match an equal sign at the beginning of a line.

Comment: [Explain this regex to me](http://blog.nu42.com/2010/09/explain-this-regex-to-me.html): Use [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/YAPE::Regex::Explain).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use different delimiters instead of `/`. For instance you could use:

```
m#/([^=]+)="(.+)"#o
```

Or

```
m~/([^=]+)="(.+)"~o
```

The advantage here of using something different than `/` is that you don't have to escape slashes, because otherwise, you'd have to use:

```
m/\/([^=]+)="(.+)"/o
  ^
```

[Or `[/]`]

`([^=]+)` is a capture group, and inside, you have `[^=]+`. `[^=]` is a negated class and will match any character which is not a `=`.

`^` behaves differently at the beginning of a character class and is not the same as `^` outside a character class which means 'beginning of line'.

As for the last part `o`, this is a flag which I haven't met so far so a little search brought me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/551569/1578604), I quote:

> The `/o` modifier is in the [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) documentation instead of the [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) documentation since it is a quote-like modifier rather than a regex modifier. That has always seemed odd to me, but that's how it is.
>
> Before Perl 5.6, Perl would recompile the regex even if the variable had not changed. You don't need to do that anymore. You could use `/o` to compile the regex once despite further changes to the variable, but as the other answers noted, `qr//` is better for that.

Answer (score 4):

1. Some regexp implementations allow you to use other special characters besides `/` as the delimiter. This is useful if you need to use that special character inside the regular expression itself, since you don't have to escape it. (In and of itself `/` is not a special character in regexp syntax, but it needs escaping if it's used in the regexp *literal* syntax of the host language.) The docs on [Perl's quote operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) mention this.
2. This is tutorial-level stuff: square brackets (`[abc]`) denote a character class - it means "any of the characters inside the brackets". (In my example, it means "either `a` or `b` or `c`.) Inside them, the `^` special character has a different meaning, it *inverts* the character class. So, `[^=]` means "any character *except* `=`", and `[^=]+` means "one or more characters that aren't `=`".

---

Quoting the docs on [Perl's RE syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Version-8-Regular-Expressions):

> You can specify a character class, by enclosing a list of characters in `[]` , which will match any character from the list. If the first character after the "[" is "^", the class matches any character not in the list.

Answer (score 2):

It is meant to match equation like expressions, to capture the key and values separately. Imagine you have a statement like `height="30px"`, and you want to capture the `height` attribute name, as well as its value `30px`.

So you have `m|/([^=]+)="(.+)"|`.

The key is supposed to be everything before the `=` is encountered. So `[^=]` captures it. The `^` is a negation metacharacter when used as the first character inside `[]` brackets. It means that it will match any character except `=`, which is what you want. The `/` is probably a mistake, if you need to capture the group, you should not use it, or if it is indeed intended, it means to literally match an opening parentheses. Since it is a special character, it needs to be escaped, that's why `\(`. if you mean to capture the group, it should be `([^=]+)`.

Next comes the `=` sign, which you don't care about. Then the quotes which contain the value. So you capture it like `"(.+)"`. the `.+` will go on matching greedily every character, including the final `"`. But then it will find that it can't match the final `"` in the regex, so it will backtrack, give up the last `"` the regex `(.+)` captured, so that leaves the string within the quotes to be captured in the group. Now you are ready to access the key and value through `$1` and `$2`. Cool, isn't it?