# Understanding with this regex in Perl without assignment

Tags: regex, perl

Can someone explain me how to understand this part of the code
The code is extracted from pfLogSumm.pl a log analyzer for postfix mail

```
while(<>) {
    next if(defined($dateStr) && ! /^$dateStr/o);
    s/: \[ID \d+ [^\]]+\] /: /o;    # lose "[ID nnnnnn some.thing]" stuff
    my $logRmdr;

    more code

}
```

I can't understand what the regex is doing because don't have a assignment, don't have a conditional, simple is there

Comment: `next .. /^$dateStr/` does nothing if `$dateStr` is undefined. Very old perl, btw.

Answer (score 1):

By default, regular expressions (and many other functions) operate on `$_`. So

```
s/: \[ID \d+ [^\]]+\] /: /o;
```

is equivalent to:

```
$_ =~ s/: \[ID \d+ [^\]]+\] /: /o;
```

This replaces `: [ID number ...]` with just `:` in the input line.

This is a common idiom that you should see in many Perl scripts, you should be used to it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar!! Solved!

Comment: One more question please! Wath is doing the regex? replacing? extractng? and whats abuot the /o modifier? Thanks again!!

Comment: It's replacing something -- that's what `s///` means. The `o` modifier tells Perl to compile the RE, but it's considered obsolete now. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550258/does-the-o-modifier-for-perl-regular-expressions-still-provide-any-benefit