# Perl regex /o optimization or bug?

Tags: regex, perl

I was reading through `perldoc perlre` and noticed this somewhat funny line:

```
o  - pretend to optimize your code, but actually introduce bugs
```

I searched through the rest of the document, but did not find another reverence to the mentioned "bugs".

Anyone know what are the bugs of using the /o flag?

Answer (score 3):

I found this in `perldoc perlfaq6`:

> In versions 5.6 and later, Perl won't recompile the regular expression
> if the variable hasn't changed, so you probably don't need the "/o"
> option. It doesn't hurt, but it doesn't help either. If you want any
> version of Perl to compile the regular expression only once even if
> the variable changes (thus, only using its initial value), you still
> need the "/o".
>
> You can watch Perl's regular expression engine at work to verify for
> yourself if Perl is recompiling a regular expression. The "use re
> 'debug'" pragma (comes with Perl 5.005 and later) shows the details.
> With Perls before 5.6, you should see "re" reporting that its
> compiling the regular expression on each iteration. With Perl 5.6 or
> later, you should only see "re" report that for the first iteration.
>
> ```
>     use re 'debug';
>
>     my $regex = 'Perl';
>     foreach ( qw(Perl Java Ruby Python) ) {
>         print STDERR "-" x 73, "\n";
>         print STDERR "Trying $_...\n";
>         print STDERR "\t$_ is good!\n" if m/$regex/;
>     }
> ```

So "it doesn't hurt" to have the /o flag. But "it doesn't help either".

Sounds to me like it's not exactly a bug.

Comment: Interestingly, using `/o` still makes regexes faster in some cases. The bugs are easily introduced by the programmer using `/o` and forgetting that the regex won't be recompiled.

Comment: @choroba Agreed on what you said.  As a secondary thought, I would argue that ```/o``` was made obsolete by the ```qr{}``` construct.  The ```qr{}``` construct also makes it a lot more obvious that the re won't be reinterpolated upon repeated usages unless one actually reassigns to the variable.  thoughts?

Comment: @Miller: Sounds right and would be nice if it were true, but... in benchmarks (e.g. [here](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1205956)) `qr{}` is much slower than the alternatives.

Comment: Re "*but it doesn't help either*", Technically, it does, but not much.

Comment: Take a look here for some benchmarks:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550258/does-the-o-modifier-for-perl-regular-expressions-still-provide-any-benefit/68489725#68489725